# elisp function that returns the current file being interpreted

Tags: emacs, elisp

Isn't there a function that returns the current file being interpreted?  That is, if I call it in foo.el, it will return "foo.el"?  The use case is in startup files.  No, I don't want user-init-file, but it is analogous to that.

Surely this has been asked before, but I cannot find the answer anywhere, huh...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah!  It's called load-file-name.

I had already been using it in one of my init files...